# Find the missing value in pandas (not NaN)

Tags: python, pandas, series, missing-data

I have a pandas series sorted in ascending order. Its values goes like 1,2,3,...,73514,73515,73516. But the no.of columns is 73515.

I need to find which value is missing. How to find?

Comment: Give more info about your data. Is the value numeric of string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly:

```
for i in range(1,73517):
    i if i not in series.to_list() else print('',end='')
```

It should print the searched value.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of python sets as well assuming the column names are of type int:

```
set(range(1,73516)).difference(set(df.columns))
```

or

```
set(range(1,73516)) - set(df.columns)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value is numeric, you can try:

```
df[df['col1'] == 0]
```

if the value is a string:

```
df[len(df['col1']) == 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Binary Search algorithm in order to have that missing value returned to you. Please check this solution and just adapt it to use pandas:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-missing-element-in-a-sorted-array-of-consecutive-numbers/

This is the most efficient solution to your problem. It takes O(logN) to execute, much faster compared to the other solution where you'd have to iterate over a range of all the values from 1 to the last element in your Series and check if each value is in the Series, which uses O(N<sup>2</sup>) because both the iteration and *in* take O(N).

Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean that you have a list ranging from 1 to 73515 and need to find if there are any values missing in this list.

One way to do this would be to make a list that has all the expected values
e.g
expected = range(1,73515)

Then you could compare the expected to your list

```
missing_values = []
for num in expected:
    if num not in original_list:
        missing_values.append(num)
```

or do the same in a list comprehension:

```
missing_values_comprehension = [num for num in expected if num not in original_list]
```

Obviously, you did mention you have the values in a Series.
You can iterate straight through those values if you want to, or you can convert those to a list first.